# c# Subtract one json's property int value from another based on another property's same value

Tags: c#, arrays, json, performance, subtraction

I have two jsons data:
Json1:

```
[
{"name":"a1", "quantity": 10 },
{"name":"a2", "quantity": 11 },
{"name":"a3", "quantity": 12 },
{"name":"a4", "quantity": 13 },
{"name":"a5", "quantity": 14 },
]
```

Json2:

```
[
{"name":"a1", "quantity": 11 },
{"name":"b1", "quantity": 1 },
{"name":"b2", "quantity": 12 },
{"name":"a3", "quantity": 13 },
{"name":"a5", "quantity": 14 },
]
```

I want Json1's quantity subtract Json2's quantity based on same "name"

The result will return all the Json1's items plus another property "differ".

```
[
{"name":"a1", "quantity": 10, "differ": -1 },
{"name":"a2", "quantity": 11, "differ": 11  }, // "a2" is not in Json2, so "differ" will be 11
{"name":"a3", "quantity": 12, "differ": -1 },
{"name":"a4", "quantity": 13, "differ": 13 },
{"name":"a5", "quantity": 14, "differ": 0 },
]
```

It takes about 2 seconds for input data(Json1 and Json2) have more than 3000-5000 items for each when using the solution below.Looking for a new solution with BETTER performance. Say less than 1 second with around 5000 items.
C# Code:

```
public string GetDiff(string json1, string json2)
{
            var json1Array = JArray.Parse(json1);
            var json2Array = JArray.Parse(json2);
            var json3Array = new JArray();
            foreach (var item in json1Array)
            {
                var name = (string) item["name"];
                var quantity = (int) item["quantity"];
                var differ = quantity;
                var itemJson2 = json2Array.Where(it => (string) it["name"] == name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemJson2 != null)
                {
                    differ = quantity - (int) itemJson2["quantity"];
                }
                json3Array.Add(new JObject() { { "name", name }, { "quantity", quantity }, { "differ", differ } });
            }
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json3Array);

}
```

Comment: Or you could just deserialize it using Text.Json, or json.net, and make your life easier. You have to fully parse it anyway

Comment: Rather than writing pseudocode, I suggest you implement your current idea in *real* code, and measure the performance. You say it would have "not good performance" - does that mean you have concrete performance requirements? How does your current idea compare with those requirements?

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks for your comment. The input data Json1 and Json2 have more than 3000-5000 items for each, it takes about 2 seconds using my method, it's not good enough, there must be a better one. I hope it can take less than 1 second.

Comment: Right, so presumably you have *actual* code rather than pseudocode now - please update your question with the real code, and include the aspects about your performance requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it using your method and a different method using dictionaries. You can find it as a dotnetfiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rS0Am8

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var json1 = @"[
        {""name"":""a1"", ""quantity"": 10 },
        {""name"":""a2"", ""quantity"": 11 },
        {""name"":""a3"", ""quantity"": 12 },
        {""name"":""a4"", ""quantity"": 13 },
        {""name"":""a5"", ""quantity"": 14 },
        ]";
        var json2 = @"[
        {""name"":""a1"", ""quantity"": 11 },
        {""name"":""b1"", ""quantity"": 1 },
        {""name"":""b2"", ""quantity"": 12 },
        {""name"":""a3"", ""quantity"": 13 },
        {""name"":""a5"", ""quantity"": 14 },
        ]";
        var retries = 10000;

        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        string result = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++)
        {
            var json1Array = JArray.Parse(json1);
            var json2Array = JArray.Parse(json2);
            var json3Array = new JArray();
            foreach (var item in json1Array)
            {
                var name = (string) item["name"];
                var quantity = (int) item["quantity"];
                var differ = quantity;
                var itemJson2 = json2Array.Where(it => (string) it["name"] == name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemJson2 != null)
                {
                    differ = quantity - (int) itemJson2["quantity"];
                }
                json3Array.Add(new JObject() { { "name", name }, { "quantity", quantity }, { "differ", differ } });
            }
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json3Array);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Variant 1 (" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms)");
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++)
        {
            var d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData[]>(json1).ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Quantity);
            var d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData[]>(json2).ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Quantity);

            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d1.Select(kvp => new JsonResultData
            {
                Name = kvp.Key,
                Quantity = kvp.Value,
                Differ = d2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) ? kvp.Value - d2[kvp.Key] : kvp.Value
            }));
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Variant 2 (" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms)");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    class JsonData
    {
        [JsonProperty("name", Order = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantity", Order = 2)]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    class JsonResultData : JsonData
    {
        [JsonProperty("differ", Order = 3)]
        public int Differ { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In DotNetFiddle, it seems like your method is quicker (approximately factor 5 to 10). However, running it locally in LINQPad, variant 2 runs up to twice as fast.

I assume, it will depend a lot on your input, and how many iterations you will have. But, as Jon Skeet suggested: It is always best to actually try it out. That's what tools like LINQPad were developed for :-)

UPDATE:

Also, not using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)` to generate the resulting JSON, but instead just creating it manually will also boost your performance. However, I would not recommend this, unless your Json structure remains as simple as you have described. In my tests, this saved about 30%. Example implementation:

```
sw.Restart();
for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++)
{
    var d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData[]>(json1).ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Quantity);
    var d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData[]>(json2).ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Quantity);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("[");
    foreach (var kvp in d1)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{{\"name\":\"{0}\",\"quantity\":{1},\"differ\":{2}}}",
            kvp.Key.Replace("\"", "\\\""),
            kvp.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            (d2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) ? kvp.Value - d2[kvp.Key] : kvp.Value).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    sb.Append("]");
    result = sb.ToString();
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Variant 3 (" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms)");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Christoph Herold, As you said it depends on the input data.  I will try you method using my data which have more than 3000 items in each Json.

Comment: @uou I just tried it with a larger json (5000 entries, as you mentioned in the comment above): The dictionary method is then MUCH faster, since your iterative search will lose against the dictionary lookup. I get times of 1,666ms vs.47ms, so a speed up of factor 35 (!) for one iteration. When I used a loop of 10, I even got a speed up factor of 90. Please let me know, if this worked out for you :-)

Comment: thanks, just have time to test you solution. It works super good 5700 entries only takes 30-40ms.